# What is the meaning of "vor den Teufel" in this sentence "Mag ich vor den Teufel nicht" in an Opera?

Tags: translation, german-to-english, phrase, archaism

I'm recently trying to understand the lyrics of the Opera "Die Entführung aus dem Serail" by Mozart.
In Act 1, Osmin's Aria "Solche hergelaufne Laffen" (one example text and English translation can be find here https://www.opera-arias.com/mozart/die-entf%C3%BChrung-aus-dem-serail/solche-hergelaufne-laffen/)

I'm interested in this line:

```
"Mag ich vor den Teufel nicht"
```

I can understand that the meaning is related to something like "I don't like", "Mag ich nicht", but I don't understand the phrase "vor den Teufel" in this sentence.

What could be a good translation of this?
Is this an archaic usage? (I know this text is from 18th century which must contains stuff that is not used today)

Any explanation would be really helpful!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What would also be helpful is the time in the video where the statement you are asking is made.

Comment: @SwissCodeMen - It's right at the start isn't it? Per the libretto on the same site: 
"Solche hergelaufne Laffen/Die nur nach den Weibern gaffen,/Mag ich vor den Teufel nicht./Denn ihr ganzes Thun und Lassen/Ist, uns auf den Dienst zu passen,/Doch mich trügt kein solch Gesicht."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Meaning of *vor*

*vor* is archaic here and would be *für* in modern German

*für* and *vor* have been used interchangeably, both with the meaning of Latin *pro*.

Two examples:

> Petrus aber stund draussen fur der thür. ([John 18:16](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Luther,+Martin/Luther-Bibel+1545/Das+Neue+Testament/Das+Johannesevangelium/Johannes+18), according to the translation of the Bible by Luther 1545)

(This is the wording Bach still used in his St. John Passion.)

In modern German, it reads:

> Petrus aber stand draußen vor der Tür. ([Adaptation from 1912](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Luther,+Martin/Luther-Bibel+1912/Das+Neue+Testament/Das+Johannesevangelium/Johannes+18#1912_16))

Another example from Immanuel Kant, using *vor* where modern German would use *für* (we say *für etw. halten* nowadays):

> Allein daß diese Regeln den allgemeinen und letzten Grund aller vernünftigen Schlußart enthalten, erhellet daraus, weil diejenige, die sonst bis daher von allen Logikern vor die erste Regel aller Vernunftschlüsse gehalten worden, den einzigen Grund ihrer Wahrheit aus den unsrigen entlehnen müssen. (I. Kant, [*Die falsche Spitzfindigkeit der vier syllogistischen Figuren*](http://www.zeno.org/Philosophie/M/Kant,+Immanuel/Die+falsche+Spitzfindigkeit+der+vier+syllogistischen+Figuren/%C2%A7+2.+Von+den+obersten+Regeln+aller+Vernunftschl%C3%BCsse))

## Literal Translations of the Phrase

The phrase would literally be translated as "I don't like it for the devil", meaning something along the lines of "Hell no, I don't like it at all".
In modern German, there is an expression *um's Verrecken nicht* ("not for croaking") with the same meaning ("no way", "not in any case") and *um* in this expression and *für* / *vor* in your quote have the same function.

## Meaning of *für* in this Construction

I cannot explain the reason why *für* / *um* is used in these construction very well. There is a sense of reciprocity involved, but it does not mean "I wouldn't like it (even) if I got the devil in return for it", I think it is more like "Devil forfend I should like it".

(As a sidenote, *um* and *für* appear to be somewhat interchangeable in German -- for instance in modern day Austrian German, *um* is actually used in the sense of German German *für*: *Du kannst meine alte Waschmaschine um 100 € kaufen.* in Austrian German would be *Du kannst meine alte Waschmaschine für 100 € kaufen*. in German German).

Comment: +1, especially for mentioning how *vor* is archaic for *für*. These were often used interchangeably, f.i., by Luther, and up to the age of Kant (which is to say, Mozart's time).

Comment: @marquinho Thanks for the hints, I added two examples to strengthen the claim.

Comment: IMHO, the combination "für den Teufel" + "nicht" is akin a double (=strong) negation of our modern "für's Leben gern."

Answer (score 4):

It's a simple intensifier. The mention of "devil" indicates that it's a strong intensifier, but the literal meaning is arbitrary, just as something "hellishly" difficult doesn't *actually* have anything to do with brimstone or mortal sins.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to say what this really meant, and it's possible that this was an idiom with bleached meaning same as todays *auf den Tod*, *etwas auf den Tod nicht ausstehen können*, or *um Gottes Willen* and *bei Leibe nicht* (thus @Killian Froth before me).

These are adverbs which mean "very much", "not at all", depending on context. As another example, *auf Teufel-komm-raus* is an adverb with more specific meaning. So *auf*, *um* and *bei* seem well precedented to me, but *vor* is illusive, except *vor allem /vorall'n* "even, of course".

As in English:

> I can't stand them for [no] shit.

It is possible that *vor den* is hypercorrect and that the preposition may be a reinterpretation of a completely different phrase.

The expression seems to feature negative concord with *devil*, which is ambiguous when interpreted as *intensive*.

Hypothesis: related to *vermögen*<sup>1</sup>, thus *ich [ver-]mag sie _ *den Teufel nicht*. This would be important for the stress pattern as the *Focus* is on the negation, accordingly stressed. That's not usually the case with adverbial phrases like that in modern German. How very poetic.

1: cf. Grimm *vermögen* 2. jmd. habhaft werden, "= mögen"
https://www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/verm%C3%B6gen